# Finding Index of element in sorted array

Tags: python, arrays

Given a code that sorts an array of integers, how do i search and find the index of each element in the sorted array.

```
def countSort(arr):
    output = [0 for i in range(256)]

    count = [0 for i in range(256)]

    result = ["" for _ in arr]

    # Store count of each integers
    for i in arr:
        count[ord(i)] += 1

    # Change count[i] so that count[i] now contains actual
    # position of this integers in output array
    for i in range(256):
        count[i] += count[i - 1]

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        output[count[ord(arr[i])] - 1] = arr[i]
        count[ord(arr[i])] -= 1

    for i in range(len(arr)):
        result[i] = output[i]
    return result
```

driver code

```
    arr = input("Enter numbers: ")
    result = countSort(arr)
    print("Sorted array is %s" % ("".join(result)))
```

This is what i tried to do but it has errors

```
      print(input("Search for Element:"))
      for k in result:
          if k not in result:
             print("Element not found", k)
          else:
             print("Index of Element is ", result.index(k))
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it has errors". You are not using the return value of `input` (other than printing it). Also the loop is unnecessary.

Comment: Is `k` supposed to be the return value of `input`?

Comment: @chepner k represents elements in sorted array which is result

Comment: I have edited your question to correct apparent indentation issues for `countSort`.  please review my edit and confirm that it matches your actual code.

Comment: The code you tried makes no sense.  Look at what it's doing:  First it inputs an element to search for, then discards the value that the user enters.  Then, having no idea what value to look for, it loops over all of the elements of the list.  For each element, it then checks to see if the element is in the list.  Well, of course it is.  How could it not be?  Then it searches the list to find the index, which it would already have if it had simply kept track.  It's an O(n**2) loop.  It should be O(log(n)) since you know the list is sorted and can therefore do a binary search.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `result`. But that raises another point: if `k not in result` will never be true if the values of `k` are *taken* from `result` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a code that let the user insert a number to search.

The code return the index of the number if it can be found in the sorted list.

**Note**: The code below uses python builtin sort and does not make use of your sorting code.

```
NUMBERS = [4, 6, 2, 12, 56, 34, 90]

sorted_numbers = sorted(NUMBERS)

number_to_search = input("Search for Element:")

try:
    idx = sorted_numbers.index(number_to_search)
    print('The index of {} is {}.'.format(number_to_search, idx))
except ValueError:
    print('Cant find the number {}.'.format(number_to_search))
```